# Is there a text editor or ide that will do this things?

Tags: ide

Is there a text editor that will let me shade certain code blocks with specific colors so I can easily find them later? Bookmarks are great, but I also wanted to shade with the same color all code blocks which are somehow related to each other.

and

When my current text editors autocreate curly braces or parentheses for me and I type what I want in between them, are there any that let me either jump to the end of the line to put a semicolon there, or "return" to type the next line, or do I always have to use the arrow key to get out of the curly braces? Perhaps there is a shortcut I'm missing?

Comment: Visual Studio has bookmarks

Comment: I'm not sure above shading with colours, however sublime text allows you to bookmark code points allowing you to quickly scroll through them with F2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think about every code editor, including [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), has bookmarks. If you're looking for a more complete IDE, it probably depends on the language you're using. For .NET languages that is Visual Studio, but you probably would have known that. For PHP, Javascript and HTML/CSS, you can use Netbeans for PHP. Netbeans is also available for Java. It is a rich editor, and I think one of the best free general purpose IDE's available.

Marking pieces of code in colors is unknown to me. I've never seen an editor that supports this. You would also need a project in which to store the start and end points of these blocks, unless you would save them as comments or so in the file itself.

Visual Studio knows *regions* which you can define by a start tag and an end tag. You can collapse and unfold an entire region at once, making it quite easy to navigate through larger files. 
But these regions are actually part of the code file, so you cannot use this for any file, because those region markers will probably make the file invalid.

I'm still wondering why any other shortcut key would be easier or more convenient than 'arrow down'..

Comment: So it's "arrow down" ? Thanks! There were a few apps which forced me to "arrow right" to the end of the line and I didn't know if "arrow down" was a universal convention or not.

Comment: Arrow down should almost always work, although some editor will jump to the end of the line if the line you're jumping to is shorter than the current position on the line you're jumping from, while other editors will move the cursor exactly one line down, filling in a gap (if the line is shorter) with fake spaces. Often these spaces will only be added if you actually start typing there. And you can always use Home and End to jump to the start or end of a line.

Comment: Thx. Now I know my key mapping is probably messed up if arrow down isn't working.